# No Audio During Cutscenes

Tags: technical-issues, thief

During cutscenes when Erin is supposed to be talking, there is no sound. I have tried reinstalling the game, changing language packs, adjusting speaker setup, I have music turned on, and I don't have Final Fantasy XIV (to delete the bin folder from). Is there any way of fixing this audio problem? Playing on Windows 10.

Comment: Final Fantasy 14 messes with Thief? How odd...

Comment: Can you please specify your platform and/or OS? Sometimes it messes with a particular update, did you try backing up from a previous system save?

Comment: @V4karian windows 10. I’ll have to get specifics later if you need them. I don’t have an older backup than the second latest version of windows and I’ve been having this problem for quite some time

Answer (score 2):

I found this **[steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239160/discussions/0/558749190684998327/)** form, which might be the one you checked already as they talk about deleting the **bin** folder if you have Final Fantasy XIV. You may have already tired it but they also say to make sure you have the **music** for the game turned on.

Although your issue is on the **Windows 10**, after looking at some other form pages it appears that the issue is not platform specific. The **PlayStation** version seems to have had a lot of problems including:

- Audio cutting in and out
- No Voices
- Audio out of sync

Currently it doesn't seem like there is any fix on our end, and with the lack of responses from the developers there doesn't seem to be any plan to fix the issue.

Comment: apologies for not responding sooner, i was out of town for a few days. i think that was the steam discussion i looked at, but I will double check it again when I get back on my pc. I can toss out another bounty if it helps me solve the problem.